# Hack User Identity ExtJS

Tags: security, extjs, extjs4

I am building a web application using ExtJs (MVC).

My biggest worry is **How to identify which user logged in my system ?**

I can do this in many ways, but what about security?
This information could be stored in 
- **Cookie** 
- **Local Storage**
- **Session Storage**

How can I make sure that someone won't use developer tools to change such information,
since everything is on the client and I am not using server sessions? Is any of the above safe?

Is there any way to use server sessions for this issue?

Would encrypting identity be safe enough for the client? In this case, what about if someone 
deletes cookies etc...

This kind of questions become even more complex when dealing with user roles. I can't find any reasonable post to handle this problem without too mush client information

Answer (score 2):

After authentication use server side sessions to store the user information (name, roles, ..). The user can't change this information cause the only thing that is on the client machine is the Session-ID.

For security you should check every request made by a client on the server side for the required permission level. Never trust the data that comes from a client.

So no nothing of what you suggest is safe, you will need server sessions.

Comment: That's right. After login, server can keep user identity using sessions. My biggest worry was how Javascript (extjs) knows about this. So I guess that after a request, in the response you can get the user information. Therefore, you can have `if else` statements to handle roles in javascript based on response data

Comment: yes, you could write a webservice to authenticate the user and in the response include all user information or you write the user object into the html site so you can access the information on every site.